# how to fix iOS Safari displaying 'a' tag style different then browser?

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Pretty straightforward question. Below are the images for reference.
here is the iOS safari from my phone.
[image: ios safari image]
And here is my browser, note that both is taken from the live server itself.
[image: browser image]

Below is the HTML and CSS code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="about-more-wrapper">
    <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inProgressModal">
        More
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.about-more-wrapper a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #666666;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 1.625rem;
}

.about-more-wrapper a:hover {
    color: #101010;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.about-more-wrapper a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 5%;
    background-color: #666666;
    height: 20%;
    width: 1px;
}

.about-more-wrapper a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 5%;
    background-color: #101010;
    height: 0%;
    width: 1px;
}
```

As you can see, there is no code displaying of the colour of which is present on the iOS.
Any help is much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: It looks like that browser auto-applied this color. Please share some screenshots of your browser Inspect ( Elements ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix to the problem! 
Since that code essentially triggers a bootstrap modal, I did everything they said
from the documentation that said to include type="button". This however is clashing with my css since i do not provided any class of buttons and hence safari just added its default button css.

I didn't see this through as i'm using Chrome as my primary development tool. But safari for mac also displays the same thing.

Removing `type="button"` fixed my issue.